# Create a function that gets data from alternative tables and database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am very new to SQL Server and I am given an assignment to create a function (which I have never done before).

Here's what the function should do:
There are three tables in the database that has date of birth.  Two of these tables are in database1 while the third table is in database2.

So my function needs to (when called/used)  go into database1 and table 1 to see if the date of birth for a specific person is available.  If yes, the grab that value.  If No, the look into the table 2.  Finally, if both tables do not have the date of birth, then go to database2 and table 3 to get the date of birth.

Is this possible?  Can a function grab data from two different database?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: It may or may not be possible.  The fact that you have to write a function has nothing to do with whether or not you have to access more than one database.  That's a matter of permissions.  I suggest that you start by writing a query and then converting the query to a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to create your function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDatOfBirth](@PersonID INT)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DateOfBirth DATE

    SELECT @DateOfBirth = DateOfBirth
    FROM Database1..Table1
    WHERE PersonID = @PersonID

    IF @DateOfBirth IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @DateOfBirth = DateOfBirth
        FROM Database1..Table2
        WHERE PersonID = @PersonID  
    END
    IF @DateOfBirth IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @DateOfBirth = DateOfBirth
        FROM Database2..Table1
        WHERE PersonID = @PersonID  
    END

RETURN(@DateOfBirth)
END
```

Disclaimer: Often scalar functions like this are performance killers, so I'd advice for other options (like using this tables on joins) in most cases.

Comment: I was going to answer the same way.  You can write one query......HOWEVER, if you write one query, it will hit all 3 tables to determine a value.  This answer...you pay the price for hit #2 and hit #3, only if you need to.

Comment: @granadaCoder I think so too. Mahmoud's answer is more useful on a set based solution (maybe creatig a view?), so it can be used on joins and probably performing better than a UDF in that context

Comment: Yeah.  It "just depends".  I like the one view with UNION in it.... but .. the second and third "option" could be a linked server.... and then you have to handle the possibility multiple rows.

Answer (score 2):

To access tables from another database, use the syntax:

```
Database.Schema.Object
```

Note that this will only work on the same server. If your databases are on different servers them you will need to create a linked server.

To create a user-defined function, check out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx